# Cloned project but don't have .env or ./env.local.yml to run code locally as they were in gitignore

Tags: node.js, yaml, environment-variables, nodeenv

Hi can someone provide me some help with this. I got given a node js project to work on but can't seem to run it as I dont have the .env or ./env/local.yml files. Is there a way I can run code locally without them? Is there a work around or do I need to create these files myself.

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create them yourself if the project doesn't work with some built-in defaults.

The project's readme should have instructions on which environment variables are required; if not, you can of course try and sleuth them yourself by looking for `process.env` usages in the code.